# Promoting Writers SE on YouTube?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I am starting a YouTube channel for writing tips, and I wanted to share Writers SE with my viewers, as it has greatly helped me with my writing endeavors.

Acting on the advice of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284552/340144), **I'd like to gauge the general public sentiment about this**, and make sure there aren't objections before I do it. Keep in mind that the channel hasn't even begun yet, so any effects will likely be small at first.

Answer (score 4):

That is a great idea!

This site will only profit from a larger number of users. Many questions receive only half-helpful answers, because the current members lack the expertise. So by all means, invite everybody over.